# Не срабатывает [self.tableView reloadData]; при PushNavigation

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Есть *ViewController*, на нем выбираю определенные данные, по кнопке перехожу на другой *ViewController*, все ок, данные отображаются.

Возвращаюсь назад, меняю данные, заново гружу *ViewController*, там во `ViewDidAppear` вызываю `[self.tableView reloadData];` — таблица не обновляется.

Пробовал делать через *Нотификации* — то же самое. Видимо, проблема в том, что ссылается на старую таблицу.

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 3):

Сложно сказать готовый ответ. Мой алгоритм при отладке работы с таблицами.

1. Поставить брейк-поинт на `[self.tableView reloadData]` и убедиться, что метод вызывается.
2. Проверить, что `self.tableView != nil`.
3. Проверить, что  `self.tableView.dataSource != nil`.
4. Поставить брейкпоинт в методе датасорса: `-numberOfSectionsInTableView:`, убедиться, что метод вызывается, проверить, что этот метод возвращает не ноль. Если метод не вызывается, то см. пп. 1-3.
5. Поставить брейкпоинт в методе датасорса: `-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`
   , убедиться, что метод вызывается, проверить, что этот метод возвращает не ноль. Если не вызывается, то см. пп. 1-4.
6. Поставить брейкпоинт в методе датасорса: `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Если вызывается, то как минимум одна секция и одна ячейка в таблице есть. Нужно проверить, чтобы возвращаемая из этого метода ячейка была хоть как-то проинициализирована данными: `cell.textLabel.text = @"Hello";`.